# How to create site setting in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-10

I'm trying to create website settings in a Laravel app. To store the settings, I created a table with two columns: "key" and "value".

My settings data can be of various types, including arrays, strings, booleans, and others. I thought I could use $casts to handle the different data types, but it's not working as expected. For example, if I set the column to cast as an array, the data stored in that column should always be an array, but that's not the case.

Can you help me figure out how to handle different data types for my website settings in Laravel?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not set the value column type to `json` aka `string` aka `VARCHAR` and store values as `JSON`? [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-json)... Or better store them directly in a JSON File

Comment: @galalem never use files... If you have a load balancer, you have to share files, thats a big no. 100% a database. And instead of VARCHAR, make the column JSON

Comment: This is a perversion of the point of using a relational database, but if you must, you can create a custom cast that serializes the values so you always get back the object you sent (assuming it's serializable). However you are always better off using a more rigid schema and if you can't define that in a relational database then consider switching to a different kind of data store that works for you